# sed: Question about sed script split files

Tags: shell, sed

I've used `sed` script to split a file to many xml files by keyword:

script:

```
#!/bin/sh
File=/home/spark/PktLog
count=0
line=(`sed -n '/?xml version="1.0" encoding/=' $File`)
num=${#line[@]}
for n in ${line[*]}
do
   [ $count -eq 0 ] && startLine=$n && continue
   let count+=1
   let endLine=n-1
   if [ $count -eq $num ]; then
      startLine=$n
      sed -n "${startLine},$ p" $File >result_${count}.txt
   else
      sed -n "${startLine},${endLine} p;q" $File >result_${count}.txt
      startLine=$n
   fi
done
```

but not split many files. I debug shell script

```
spark@ubuntu:~$ sh -x split.sh 
+ File=/home/spark/PktLog
+ count=0
+ line=(`sed -n '/?xml version="1.0" encoding/=' $File`)
++ sed -n '/?xml version="1.0" encoding/=' /home/spark/PktLog
+ num=333
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ startLine=1
+ continue
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ startLine=137
+ continue
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ startLine=244
+ continue
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ startLine=415
+ continue
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ startLine=522
+ continue
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ startLine=674
+ continue
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ startLine=780
+ continue
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ startLine=932
+ continue
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ startLine=1038
+ continue
+ for n in '${line[*]}'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
```

How to fix the error? Thanks!

Comment: That is not a sed script, it's a shell script that invokes sed multiple times and uses other constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the line numbers of something so you can loop over the file repeatedly is an antipattern.  `sed` could do this with a bit of help, but it just makes more sense to switch to a higher-level tool for this.

```
awk '/\?xml version="1.0" encoding/ {
    if (f) close(f);
    f = "result_" ++i }
  { print >f }' "$File"
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, I left the `if` just for clarity but added the missing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
File=/home/spark/PktLog
count=0
startLine=(`sed -n -e '/?xml version="1.0" encoding/=' $File`)
fileEnd=`sed -n '$=' $File`
endLine=(`echo ${startLine[*]} | awk -v a=$fileEnd '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf("%d ",$i-1);print a}'`)

let maxIndex=${#startLine[@]}-1

for n in `seq 0 $maxIndex`

do
    sed -n "${startLine[$n]},${endLine[$n]}p" $File >result_${n}.xml
done

echo $startLine[@]
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons why that script will be orders of magnitude slower than the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52143902/1745001), It also has additional bugs, is bash-specific without calling the bash interpreter, and uses deprecated constructs.